# animations on ng-repeat within ui-bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I believe I have found a bug with ui-bootstrap, I reported an issue here:
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4222

Would anyone have any tips on how to write a workaround for this in the meantime until it gets solved?

Basically, angular's animation hooks are not applied to elements within a ui-bootstrap modal, the plunker is posted in the link above

Any help much appreciated